# Generating variations in C++ - all r-digit numbers among n given digits?

Tags: c++

I have a program in which I have to generate all r-digit numbers (if r is 2 - all 2-digit numbers) among n digits (these ought to be all numbers from 1 to n inclusive). My question is how can I do this recursively or iteratively, for example if `n = 3 and r = 2`, the result should be `12 13 21 23 31 32`.

Comment: And what's wrong with your code? What's the current behavior?

Comment: Must digits be unique or is repetition allowed, as long as the total length is `r` digits?